# DNS Errors On Dual Boot Machine

Tags: networking, dual-boot, dns

I'm wanting to get more into using Linux as my daily OS, so I figured I'd dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu (custom PC with a 3700X and a 5700XT, if it matters). However, I can't do much because most websites won't load, citing a DNS error. First thing I tried was switching from 21.04 down to the most recent LTS build, which didn't solve the issue. I've tried different servers; the public ones and the ones my Comcast router/modem says it uses. Neither worked. I've also tried a full shutdown, thinking that maybe a quick restart caused an issue with the modem. Also produced no results. At this point I'm not sure what to try, as neither Ubuntu or networking are things I'd consider myself good with.

I assume there's some commands I can run for more in depth diagnostics.

Comment: if you still have your win10 element running, are you able to use the Live CD to `try ubuntu`, without installing it? See [this reference](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started)

Comment: Yeah I could give that a shot, not sure why I didn't think to try it already